# Matar un proceso en C

Tags: c, proceso

La idea es, a partir de el ingreso de un pid por parte del usuaro, detenerlo, pero no esta funcionando, tienen alguna idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

char proceso;
char command;
for(;;){
    command="kill ";
    printf( "Aca listo los procesos" );
    fflush(stdout); 
    system("ps -eo user,pid,%mem,%cpu --width 9 --sort -rss | head");
    fflush(stdout); 
    printf("Deme un pid para detener" );
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s",&proceso);
    printf( "deteniendo el proceso PID: %s\n", proceso );
    fflush(stdout);
    command=command+proceso;
    printf( "El comando es: %s\n", command );
    fflush(stdout);
    int system(const char * command);

     } 


    return 0;

     }
```

Comment: This is stackoverflow in spanish.

Comment: Quita `const char *` de la invocación a system, y el int que has puesto delante.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te falta enviar la señal al proceso:

Recuerda que el comando `kill` termina los procesos enviandoles una señal:

Ejemplo: `kill -9 $PID` En este caso 9 es el numero de la señal.

Mientras que `killall`, permite que lo hagas con el nombre del proceso.

`kill` -> [Aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)
`killall` -> [Aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall)

Cabe aclarar que para "matar" el proceso debes tener el privilegio sobre el proceso.

Comment: La señal en el comando kill es opcional. Si no la pones envía por defecto SIGTERM